# 2 counting questions after exam

Tags: probability, combinatorics, factorial

Hi I just wrote a probability midterm and would like to verify a couple of the short counting questions worth a point each.

I understand it's better to ask one question at a time but it seems like a waste to separate such short simple questions

> Q1: 6 People are waiting for the bus, considering 2 of the people refuse to stand behind each other what is the total number of ways they can line up?

6! ways they can line up in general.
If A lines up in first place that removes 4! combinations
If A lines up in last place that removes 4! combinations 
If A lines up in place 2,3,4,5 that removes 2*4! combinations 4 times

I got 6! - 10x4! total

> Q2: 3 balls are randomly dropped into 3 bins. What is the probability of exactly one bin being empty?

$3^3$ total combinations = 81

012 (3x2 combinations) = 6

021 (3x2 combinations) = 6

102 (3x2 combinations) = 6

201 (3x2 combinations) = 6

120 (3x2 combinations) = 6

210 (3x2 combinations) = 6

so $\frac{36}{81} = \frac{4}{9}$

Any mistakes?

Comment: your solution for first question is right but i doubt your solution of second question..............can you clarify are balls identical in your second question ?

Comment: yeah the balls are identical

Comment: In the solution though I treat them as labeling ball 1, 2, and 3 and consider all possible orders. Wouldn't it still work out though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second, $3^3=27,$ not $81$.  When you count the number of combinations for $012$ you just need to choose the ball in the $1$, so there are only $3$ combinations.  This gives $\frac {18}{27}=\frac 23$.  As a check $111$ gives $6$ combinations and $003$ in some order gives $3$, making the total $27$.

Comment: Right! Silly mistake on my part, I ended up writing a script to double check all the variations and it indeed returned 18/27